# Error in Using Association Rule on SAS Enterprise Miner

Tags: transactions, sas, associations, enterprise-miner

I just started using SAS EM. And I imported an excel file with three variables into SAS EM: Customerid, Item and Sequence. Sequence stands for the sequence of transaction in this person's shopping history).

I linked the file import node with association node. However after I ran the association node, it kept throwing out error messages like this: "Must have at least 1 transaction data set(s)". It's the same error message with market basket analysis node. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

when you define the data source define the role of the dataset as "transaction".
this will be on Data Source Attributes page of "Data Source Wizard"

Answer (score 2):

The correct answer is actually what both pratiksha and user3659823 have answered.

1. You must define the role of your dataset as **"Transaction"**.
2. You should have "**Target"** and **"ID"** role in your *dateset variables.*

Answer (score 1):

In your transaction node,

Set your product's role to **TARGET**

your unique ID as **ID**

Answer (score 1):

> One option will be to select in the **Role**: ***Value*** *"Transaction"* ,in purple bellow, from default *Value* **Raw** for input data, e.g. see screenshot bellow:

[image]